# execution of conditional operators

Tags: c, conditional-statements, logical-operators

```
int j=4;
(!j!=1)?printf("Welcome"):printf("Bye");
```

In the above code segment, according to me, first `j!=1` will result in true and `!true` is false which must result in printing `Bye` but I get `Welcome` as the output.

Can anyone explain this one?

Comment: Take a look at the [operator precedence table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) and answer it yourself.

Comment: Obviously it should have been written as `j??!!j!=1? printf("Welcome"):printf("Bye");` instead, for clarity.

Comment: It'd be nice if you marked one of the answers as the Answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!` executed first because unary operator `!` has a higher precedence than `!=`.

`!4` become `0` then `0 != 1` become `true`.

So, output is `Welcome`.

Answer (score 2):

`!j!=1` is `(!j)!=1`, not `!(j!=1)`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `!` (NOT) has higher [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than `!=` so...

```
j = 4; // 4
!j // 0
```

In your condition, `0 != 1` will be true so "Welcome" is printed.

For your desired outcome, your condition would have to be `!(j!=1)`.

Answer (score 2):

The Logical NOT operator `!` has a higher precedence than the Not Equal To operator `!=`

So your condition is equivalent to `((!j) != 1)`

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence

Answer (score 2):

The unary operator **'!'** has a higher precedence than **'!='**.

Read - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators_precedence.htm.